# PHP - MySql SELECT WHERE value = string JSON

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, where-clause

through a cURL connection, I can pick up data, from Json files, placed on a remote server. In particular, the codes of some products, which thanks to a **foreach**

```
foreach($data['results'] as $key=>$val){ 

$codici_hotel = $val['hotel_code'];
echo $codici_hotel.",";

 }
```

I can see on video:

```
1074d0,19f726,1072ba,107104,183444,112438,15d8ab,1b326e,19d885,189b95,1071bf,107155,193e61,10aab2,138752,18dd7d,19d7f9,117b0d,1071b8,1398c4,107039,110851,107124,110669
```

Now I need to use that string to run a select on a local database, such as:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE code = ('$codici_hotel')";
```

What is the correct sql string?
Thanks for your help

> CODE UPDATE USED

```
 $codici_hotel_arr = array();
foreach($data['results'] as $key=>$val){ 
$codici_hotel_arr[] = $val['hotel_code'];
 }
$codici_hotel =  "'".implode(",",$codici_hotel_arr)."'";
$conn2 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn2->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn2->connect_error);
} 
$sql2 = "SELECT name FROM hotels WHERE code IN ('$codici_hotel')";

$result2 = $conn2->query($sql2);

if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
       $nome_hotel =  $row2["name"] ;

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn2->close();

    echo $nome_hotel;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your all codes in string enclosed with `'`. Then use `IN` clause of mysql. change your code as below

```
$codici_hotel_arr = array();
foreach($data['results'] as $key=>$val){ 

$codici_hotel_arr[] = $val['hotel_code'];

 }

$codici_hotel =  "'".implode(",",$codici_hotel_arr)."'";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE code IN ($codici_hotel)";
```

Comment: You have to apologize, but I made a mistake in my request. I did not specify that the sql search query should be made for each single product code returned by "$codes_hotel". It's possible?

Comment: Have you tested my code? My code will return all data for all codes specified in `$codes_hotel`

Comment: Yes. I've tested your code, but the result is 0.

Precise that product codes may also not be present in my database. How can I get sql data only of $codici_hotel in the database?

Comment: Have you change `=` with `IN` in your sql query?

Comment: I've updated the post with the code I'm using, thanks to your report. It returns 0 records.

Comment: Remove `''` from  query `SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE code = ('$codici_hotel')`change it to `SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE code = ($codici_hotel)`. check in my answer I already done that

Comment: Nothing! If I run SELECT name FROM hotels WHERE code IN ('19f726'), I will return $hotel_name because it is present on a DB line. I think the search stops at the first $hotel codes, as it does not exist in db.